# How do I create a custom modal NSWindow?

Tags: cocoa

I want to create a custom NSWindow that acts as a modal dialog. By custom I mean it has normal user controls in the window, with a "OK" and "Cancel" buttons. The dialog will contain read only information, and have a few checkboxes, secure edit fields, etc.

The MainMenu.xib file will have the normal Window visible at launch, plus include the custom NSWindow (which is NOT visible at launch).

I am trying to find example code to launch the window in modal mode (after the app initializes and launches main window), and on "OK" run a process, and on success of that process hide the dialog. Or on failure, keep the dialog up, but show an error sheet on the dialog.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8277295/creating-a-fully-customized-nsalert

Answer (score 4):

You want to look at `NSApplication`’s `-runModalForWindow:` and/or `-runModalSession:` methods. Note that using modal windows is generally a bad idea and if it’s at all possible to avoid doing so, you should; that said, sometimes needs must.

As far as launching a process, waiting for it to finish and so on, you can probably do what you need with `NSTask`, although you don’t provide sufficient detail to be certain.  You’d probably want to observe `NSTaskDidTerminateNotification` to tell you when the task had finished.

See

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OperatingSystem/OperatingSystem.html

for more on `NSTask` and

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Concepts/UsingModalWindows.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000223-CJBEADBA

for more about modal `NSWindow` usage.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at NSApplication's [`-runModalForWindow:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSApplication/runModalForWindow%3a) method, and "[Using Application-Modal Dialogs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Sheets/Tasks/UsingAppModalDialogs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001207-BABFIBIA)."